# Plotting coordinates on a grid correctly?

Tags: python

I wasn't sure what to title this question, and I am new to this platform and python, so apologies in advance.

I have a list which acts as a grid. When the user picks a coordinate, that square is labelled as 1. Then, in 3 specific locations, a 2 is placed, showing the next possible locations.
Here is the wording in the question I'm working on:

```
Given a 5x5 grid, the numbers 1 to 25 are to be placed without repetition in the grid. The placement rule is that given the number k occupying co-ordinates (x, y), 1 <= k < 25, the number k+1 can be placed in any unoccupied square on the board with the following co-ordinates (z, w):
(z, w) = (x +/- 3, y)
(z, w) = (x, y +/- 3)
(z, w) = (x +/- 2, y +/- 2)

For example, given the starting position of 1 at (1, 2), the number 2 can be placed in any of the squares marked with a *.
+-------------------+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+-------------------+
| 1 |   |   | * |   |
+-------------------+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+-------------------+
|   |   | * |   |   |
+-------------------+
| * |   |   |   |   |
+-------------------+


Your program should repeatedly offer 3 options: A - Problem A; B - Problem B; X - exit program.
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
grid = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
]
start_coords = (int(input("Co-ordinate 1 (x):\t"))-1, int(input("Co-ordinate 1 (y):\t"))-1)
start_x, start_y = start_coords
valid_moves = [(3, 0), (0, 3), (2, 2)]
grid[4-start_y][start_x] = 1

for i in range (3):
  try:
    grid[(4-start_y)+valid_moves[i][1]][start_x+valid_moves[i][0]] = 2
  except:
    grid[(4-start_y)-valid_moves[i][1]][start_x-valid_moves[i][0]] = 2

for i in range (5):
  print(grid[i])
```

When I put my starting coordinate as (2, 4), everything works fine outputting this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 2], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0], 
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

and when the starting coordinates are (5, 1), everything works fine outputting this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2], 
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

However, if I put (3, 3), two of the points are wrong, and it outputs this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 2, 0, 2]
```

Why are two of the 2s still showing, instead of just not showing up?
I want it to output this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

What is the problem here and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot about that part.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to achieve. If you simply want to put the numbers from 1-25 randomly onto a grid you could simply create a list(range(1,26)) and then shuffle this list. Finally cast this into a numpy array and reshape the numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the answer for (3,3) is supposed to be

```
[2, 0, 0, 0, 2], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[2, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

based on the challenge description.

If so, I spot 2 mistakes in your implementation

1) (-2,+2) and (+2,-2) are 2 moves you do not account for.

2) in python array[-1] returns the last element of a list. Negative numbers are accepted indexes in python and will not throw an exception, but your code relies on it with your except cause.

```
grid = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
]
start_coords = (int(input("Co-ordinate 1 (x):\t"))-1, int(input("Co-ordinate 1 (y):\t"))-1)
start_x, start_y = start_coords
valid_moves = [(3, 0), (0, 3), (2, 2), (-3,0), (0,-3), (-2,2),(-2,-2),(2,-2)]
grid[4-start_y][start_x] = 1

for valid_move in valid_moves:
    new_y =  4-start_y+valid_move[1]
    new_x =  start_x+valid_move[0]
    if new_x >= 0 and new_x <= 4 and new_y >= 0 and new_y <= 4:
        grid[new_y][new_x] = 2

for i in range (5):
  print(grid[i])
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helps!